# How to create a mapping for Insert mode but not for the autocomplete submode in Vim?

Tags: vim

I have these insert mode mappings in my `.vimrc` file:

```
imap <C-e> <C-o>A
imap <C-a> <C-o>I
```

They make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> move the cursor to the start and end of the line without leaving insert mode, *a la* emacs keybindings.

However, I just realized that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> mapping introduces a conflict with the autocompletion submode. The documentation in [`:help complete_CTRL-E`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#complete_CTRL-E) states:

> When completion is active, you can use CTRL-E to stop it and go back to the originally typed text.

Thus, my <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> mapping interferes with this. Is there a way that I can make <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> jump to the end of the line only if auto-completion is not active?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is no proper way to test whether the
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>-completion mode is active or not.
However, the following two workarounds are possible.

**1.** If one uses the popup menu to choose from the list of available
completions (especially in the case of `menuone` set in the `completeopt`
option), an acceptable solution might be the mapping

```
inoremap <expr> <c-e> pumvisible() ? "\<c-e>" : "\<c-o>A"
```

**2.** A general solution can be based on a side effect: In the
completion submode, it is disallowed to enter Insert mode recursively
(see `:helpgrep Note: While completion`), so if an attempt to do so
fails, we can suppose that we are in the midst of a completion:

```
inoremap <c-e> <c-r>=InsCtrlE()<cr>
function! InsCtrlE()
    try
        norm! i
        return "\<c-o>A"
    catch
        return "\<c-e>"
    endtry
endfunction
```

Comment: Or as a nice expression mapping: `inoremap <expr> <c-e> pumvisible() ? "\<c-e>" : "\<c-o>A"`

Comment: I have `completeopt=menu,preview` (which is the default), but your solution works fine for me. I can live with it if `<c-e>` doesn't work  as expected when autocomplete offers a single suggestion, because in that instance I'm unlikely to want to dismiss the suggestion. I usually only want to dismiss the autocomplete menu if it offers too many suggestions, and I could refine the list by cancelling it then typing a couple more characters.

Comment: @nelstrom:  It seems that I have found a general solution to the problem!  Please see the latest update of the answer (and let me know if you have any issues with new mapping).

Comment: @ib - That is a very clever solution. Cheers!

Comment: @nelstrom: I'm sure you're aware of this but I `set completeopt+=longest` to take care of the problem you describe in your comment. Is there any reason in particular you don't want to use this?

Comment: @Peter:  Note that while the first mapping could be transformed into an expression mapping seamlessly, the second one could not because the `:normal` command is blocked inside expression mappings.